# How do I put the PK of the parent table directly into the PK of the child table?

Tags: mysql

```
parent table(resinfo)
res_no (PK)(auto_increment)
res_name
res_birth
res_Phone1
res_Phone2
res_Email
res_addrBasic

child table
crr_no (PK)(auto_increment)
crr_com
crr_dept
crr_pos
crr_addt
crr_grdt
res_no

child table 
edu_no (PK)(auto_increment)
edu_org
edu_mjr
edu_addt
edu_grdt
edu_state
res_no
```

'''

```
<insert id="registInfo">
    INSERT INTO

  resinfo(res_no,res_name,res_birth,res_Phone1,res_Phone2,res_Phone3,
res_Email,res_addrBasic,
    res_addrDetail,res_regDate,res_title,user_id)
    VALUES(default,#{resName},#{resBirth},#{resPhone1},#{resPhone2},#{resPhone3},#{resEmail},#{resAddrbasic},
    #{resAddrdetail},default,#{resTitle},#{userId})
</insert>

<insert id="registCrr">
        <selectKey keyProperty="resNo" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
        </selectKey>
    INSERT INTO
    rescrr(crr_no,crr_com,crr_dept,crr_pos,crr_addt,crr_grdt,res_no)
    VALUES
    <foreach collection="crrList" item="list" separator=" , ">
    (default,#{list.crrCom},#{list.crrDept},#{list.crrPos},#{list.crrAddt},#{list.crrGrdt},#{resNo})
    </foreach>
</insert>

<insert id="registCert">
        <selectKey keyProperty="resNo" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
        </selectKey>
    INSERT INTO
    rescert(cert_no,cert_name,cert_org,cert_date,res_no)
    VALUES
    <foreach collection="certList" item="list" separator=" , ">
    (default,#{list.certName},#{list.certOrg},#{list.certDate},#{resNo})
    </foreach>

</insert>

<insert id="registEdu">
    <selectKey keyProperty="resNo" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
    </selectKey>
    INSERT INTO
    resedu(edu_no,edu_org,edu_mjr,edu_addt,edu_grdt,edu_state,res_no)
    VALUES
    <foreach collection="eduList" item="list" separator=" , ">
    (default,#{list.eduOrg},#{list.eduMjr},#{list.eduAddt},#{list.eduGrdt},#{list.eduState},#{resNo})
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

**First of all, I'm sorry I'm not good at English**

**Also, this is my first time on Stack Overflow, so please understand if there are any violations of the rules.**

MY Intent

I want to INSERT the parent's PK (res_no) into the res_no of the child table.

However, insert query is repeated,,

LAST_INSERT_ID() recognizes the auto_increment of the child table's PK(crr_no,edu_no).

I think
LAST_INSERT_ID() seems to get the most recent AUTO_INCREMENT value,

Therefore, the child table does not contain the same value as the parent table's PK(res_no).

How do I fix it?

Thank you for watching

[My JSP Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7MZB.png)

Comment: I tried to explain it in as much detail as possible, but if it's not enough, I'll add it right away I'm sorry

Comment: I am trying to use SELECT MAX(PK) FROM parent table instead of LAST insert id

Comment: Your PK in child tables shouldn't be AUTO_INCREMENT. *I want to INSERT the parent's PK (res_no) into the res_no of the child table.* When you insert into child you'd have some identifying info which allows to define what row from parent must be used (according unique key must exist in parent table). Use it in INSERT .. SELECT query.